# Multiple ip addresses with different network routes on the same interface on debian

Tags: linux, tcp, routes, debian, iptables

I'd like to configure a debian box with multiple ip addresses (in the same subnet) on the same physical NIC in debian, while every address should use it's own network route.

I think it won't be able using `ip addr add`, but is it possible using pseudo interfaces like eth0:0 ? Or does the linux TCP stack prevent this? And if it's possible, how do I bind multiple default routes to their (pseudo-)interface or ip address? will it be able using iptables roules and with which?

Comment: If all your addresses are in the same subnet, how will the kernel know which one to use to get to a given destination IP?

Comment: Incoming packages would be assigned to the virtual net dev (e.g. eth0:0). This works - confirmed!

If a service binds to an ip address the traffic is routed over the given virtual net dev. This also works - confirmed!

But could I assign different routes to such devices if they're on the same subnet? It looks like as there's only one global routing table.

Would it work by setting marks with iptables?

Comment: AIUI, virtual net devices are a `ipconfig` hack and they don't really exist in the kernel at all. If you use the new `ip` there are no virtual devices, instead a single device can have multiple addresses. And the route entries, created with `ip route` have a `src`parameter that is the source IP, maybe that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are not required to do this You can do this with iproute2

```
ip addr add <ip> dev eth0
```

you then add routing to a ip specific route table

```
ip route add subnet dev eth0 table <tableid>   
ip route add default via <GATEWAY> table <tableid>
```

Then add a rule to match the ip so that it uses the specific table

```
ip rule add from any to <ip> lookup <tableid>
ip route add from <ip> to any lookup <tableid>
```

This can get pretty confusing because the routing is now multiple routing tables